# Haskell Happy parser error mismatching types and infinite type

Tags: haskell, happy

Writing a Oberon-like language parser, I'm having troubles compiling the parser after I've updated it to be able to define more procedures on the same level, and not only nested one inside the other.

This is my lexer:

```
{
module Lexer where
}

%wrapper "basic"

$alpha      = [a-zA-Z]
$digit      = [0-9]
$validChar  = [^\"]

tokens :-

  $white+                             ;
  "PROCEDURE"                 { \s -> KW_TokenProcedure }
  "END"                       { \s -> KW_TokenEnd }
  ";"                         { \s -> KW_TokenSemiColon }
  $alpha [$alpha $digit \_]*  { \s -> TokenVariableIdentifier s }

{

-- The token type:
data Token =
  KW_TokenProcedure               |
  KW_TokenEnd                     |
  KW_TokenSemiColon               |
  TokenVariableIdentifier String  |
    deriving (Eq,Show)
}
```

This is my parser:

```
{
module Main where
import Lexer
import Tools
}

%name myParse
%tokentype { Token }
%error { parseError }

%token
  KW_PROCEDURE          { KW_TokenProcedure }
  KW_END                { KW_TokenEnd }
  ';'                   { KW_TokenSemiColon }
  identifier            { TokenVariableIdentifier $$ }

%%

ProcedureDeclarationList  :   ProcedureDeclaration                              { $1 }
                          |   ProcedureDeclaration ';' ProcedureDeclarationList { $3 : $1 }

ProcedureDeclaration  : ProcedureHeading ';' ProcedureBody identifier   {
                                                                          do
                                                                            let newProc = $1  -- Crea la nuova procedura
                                                                            let procBody = $3
                                                                            addProcedureToProcedure newProc procBody
                                                                        }

ProcedureHeading        :   KW_PROCEDURE identifier { defaultProcedure { procedureName = $2 } }

ProcedureBody           : KW_END                                    { Nothing }
                        | DeclarationSequence KW_END                { Just $1 }

DeclarationSequence     :    ProcedureDeclarationList                 { $1 }

{
parseError :: [Token] -> a
parseError _ = error "Parse error"

main = do
  inStr <- getContents
  let result = oLikeParse (alexScanTokens inStr)
  putStrLn ("result: " ++ show(result))
}
```

And this is the module where the types and some utility functions are defined:

```
module Tools where

data Procedure = Procedure {    procedureName :: String,
                                procedureProcedures :: [Procedure] } deriving (Show)

defaultProcedure = Procedure {  procedureName = "",
                                procedureProcedures = [] }

addProcedureToProcedure :: Procedure -> Maybe Procedure -> Procedure
addProcedureToProcedure procDest Nothing            = Procedure {   procedureName = (procedureName procDest),
                                                                    procedureProcedures = (procedureProcedures procDest) }
addProcedureToProcedure procDest (Just procToAdd)   = Procedure {   procedureName = (procedureName procDest),
                                                                    procedureProcedures = (procedureProcedures procDest) ++ [procToAdd] }
```

The errors the compiler is giving me are these two:

- `Couldn't match type ‘[Procedure]’ with ‘Procedure’`
- `Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: t4 ~ [t4]`

I've isolated the problem and I know for sure that if I remove the second case of my `ProcedureDeclarationList` everything compiles fine, but I can't recognize more procedures on the same level.

---

UPDATE

I've changed the my data structure so that I'm not using `Maybe Procedure` anymore and I won't need a list of two types, but I still have a problem with mismatching types.

This is my updated parser:

```
{
module Main where
import Lexer
import Tools
}

%name myParse
%tokentype { Token }
%error { parseError }

%token
  KW_INTEGER            { KW_TokenInteger }
  KW_REAL               { KW_TokenReal }
  KW_BOOLEAN            { KW_TokenBoolean }
  KW_CHAR               { KW_TokenChar }
  KW_PROCEDURE          { KW_TokenProcedure }
  KW_END                { KW_TokenEnd }
  KW_VAR                { KW_TokenVar }
  ';'                   { KW_TokenSemiColon }
  ','                   { KW_TokenComa }
  ':'                   { KW_TokenColon }
  identifier            { TokenVariableIdentifier $$ }

%%

ProcedureDeclarationList  :   ProcedureDeclaration                              { [$1] }
                          |   ProcedureDeclaration ';' ProcedureDeclarationList { $1:$3 }

ProcedureDeclaration  : ProcedureHeading ';' ProcedureBody identifier { defaultDeclaration { declarationType = DT_Procedure, procedureDeclared = (addBodyToProcedure $1 $3)} }

IdentifiersList     :   identifier                      { [$1] }
                    |   identifier ',' IdentifiersList  { $1:$3 }

VariableDeclaration : IdentifiersList ':' type          { createVariablesDefinitionsOfType $1 $3 }

ProcedureHeading    : KW_PROCEDURE identifier { defaultProcedure { procedureName = $2 } }

ProcedureBody     : KW_END                                      { [] }
                  | DeclarationSequence KW_END                  { $1 }

DeclarationSequence   : KW_VAR VariableDeclarationList ';'      { $2 }
                      | ProcedureDeclarationList                { $1 }

VariableDeclarationList : VariableDeclaration                             { [$1] }
                        | VariableDeclaration ';' VariableDeclarationList { $1:$3 }

type        :   KW_INTEGER    { Integer }
            |   KW_REAL       { Float }
            |   KW_BOOLEAN    { Boolean }
            |   KW_CHAR       { Char }

{
parseError :: [Token] -> a
parseError _ = error "Parse error"

main = do
  inStr <- getContents
  let result = oLikeParse (alexScanTokens inStr)
  putStrLn ("result: " ++ show(result))
}
```

This is my updated lexer:

```
{
module Lexer where
}

%wrapper "basic"

$alpha      = [a-zA-Z]
$digit      = [0-9]
$validChar  = [^\"]

tokens :-

  $white+                             ;
  "INTEGER"                   { \s -> KW_TokenInteger }
  "REAL"                      { \s -> KW_TokenReal }
  "BOOLEAN"                   { \s -> KW_TokenBoolean }
  "CHAR"                      { \s -> KW_TokenChar }
  "PROCEDURE"                 { \s -> KW_TokenProcedure }
  "END"                       { \s -> KW_TokenEnd }
  "VAR"                       { \s -> KW_TokenVar }
  ";"                         { \s -> KW_TokenSemiColon }
  ","                         { \s -> KW_TokenComa }
  ":"                         { \s -> KW_TokenColon }
  $alpha [$alpha $digit \_]*  { \s -> TokenVariableIdentifier s }

{

-- The token type:
data Token =
  KW_TokenInteger                 |
  KW_TokenReal                    |
  KW_TokenBoolean                 |
  KW_TokenChar                    |
  KW_TokenVar                     |
  KW_TokenProcedure               |
  KW_TokenEnd                     |
  KW_TokenSemiColon               |
  KW_TokenComa                    |
  KW_TokenColon                   |
  TokenVariableIdentifier String  |
    deriving (Eq,Show)
}
```

And this is my updated tools module:

```
module Tools where

data AttributeType  = String
                    | Float
                    | Char
                    | Integer
                    | Boolean
                    deriving (Show, Eq)

data Attribute = Attribute {    attributeName :: String,
                                attributeType :: AttributeType,
                                stringValue :: String,
                                floatValue :: Float,
                                integerValue :: Integer,
                                charValue :: Char,
                                booleanValue :: Bool } deriving (Show)

data Procedure = Procedure {    procedureName :: String,
                                attributes :: [Attribute],
                                procedureProcedures :: [Procedure] } deriving (Show)

data DeclarationType    = DT_Variable
                        | DT_Constant
                        | DT_Procedure
                        deriving (Show, Eq)

data Declaration = Declaration {    declarationType     :: DeclarationType,
                                    attributeDeclared   :: Attribute,
                                    procedureDeclared   :: Procedure } deriving (Show)

defaultAttribute = Attribute {  attributeName = "",
                                attributeType = Integer,
                                stringValue = "",
                                floatValue = 0.0,
                                integerValue = 0,
                                charValue = ' ',
                                booleanValue = False }

defaultProcedure = Procedure {  procedureName = "",
                                attributes = [],
                                procedureProcedures = [] }

defaultDeclaration = Declaration {  declarationType = DT_Variable,
                                    attributeDeclared = defaultAttribute,
                                    procedureDeclared = defaultProcedure }

addAttributeToProcedure :: Procedure -> Attribute -> Procedure
addAttributeToProcedure proc att = Procedure {  procedureName = (procedureName proc),
                                                attributes = (attributes proc) ++ [att],
                                                procedureProcedures = (procedureProcedures proc) }

addProcedureToProcedure :: Procedure -> Procedure -> Procedure
addProcedureToProcedure procDest procToAdd  = Procedure {   procedureName = (procedureName procDest),
                                                            attributes = (attributes procDest),
                                                            procedureProcedures = (procedureProcedures procDest) ++ [procToAdd] }

addBodyToProcedure :: Procedure -> [Declaration] -> Procedure
addBodyToProcedure procDest []          =   procDest
addBodyToProcedure procDest declList    = do 
                                            let decl = head declList
                                            let declType = declarationType decl

                                            if declType == DT_Variable || declType == DT_Constant then 
                                                addBodyToProcedure (addAttributeToProcedure procDest (attributeDeclared decl)) (tail declList)
                                            else
                                                addBodyToProcedure (addProcedureToProcedure procDest (procedureDeclared decl)) (tail declList)

createVariablesDefinitionsOfType :: [String] -> AttributeType -> [Declaration]
createVariablesDefinitionsOfType namesList t = map (\x -> defaultDeclaration { declarationType = DT_Variable, attributeDeclared = (defaultAttribute {attributeName = x, attributeType = t})} ) namesList
```

This is the schema of the production types:

```
PRODUCTION                  TYPE
---------------             ---------------
ProcedureDeclarationList    [Declaration]
ProcedureDeclaration        Declaration
IdentifiersList             [String]
VariableDeclaration         [Declaration]
ProcedureHeading            Procedure
ProcedureBody               [Declaration]
DeclarationSequence         [Declaration]
VariableDeclarationList     [Declaration]
type                        AttributeType
```

This are the only 3 errors I get now:

- `Couldn't match type ‘[Declaration]’ with ‘Declaration’` x2
- `Couldn't match type ‘Declaration’ with ‘[Declaration]’`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping track of the types of each production with comments will help you track down type errors.

Here the types each production should have:

```
Production                            Type
--------------                        ---------
ProcedureHeading                      Procedure
ProcedureDeclaration                  Procedure
ProcedureDeclarationList              [ Procedure ]
DeclarationSequence                   [ Procedure ]
ProcedureBody                         Maybe Procedure
```

Now check each of your production rules to see if they have the correct type.

1. `ProcedureHeading` returns `defaultProcedure` with a changed name, so that's ok.
2. `ProcedureDeclaration` returns the result of a call to `addProcedureToProcedure`, so that checks out. Note that the second argument to the `addProcedureToProcedure` call is `$3` which refers to the result of a `ProcedureBody` production, so that means the return type of that production must be a `Maybe Procedure`.
3. `ProcedureDeclarationList` has problems. The production rules should read:

   ```
   ProcedureDeclarationList
     : ProcedureDeclaration                              { [ $1 ] }
     | ProcedureDeclaration ';' ProcedureDeclarationList { $1 : $3 }
   ```

`[$1]` makes a list out of a single Procedure, and `$1:$3` prepends a single Procedure to a list of Procedures.

4. `DeclarationSequence` is simply a `ProcedureDeclarationList`, so that checks out.
5. As noted in step 2, `ProcedureBody` has to be a `Maybe Procedure`. The rule for `KW_END` is fine, but the second rule needs some work:

   ```
   ProcedureBody
       | KW_END                     { Nothing }
       | DeclarationSequence KW_END { ??? }
   ```

From a `DeclarationSequence` (which is a `[Procedure]`) we have to produce a `Maybe Procedure`. This is where your problem is. `Just $1` has type `Maybe [Procedure]`, so that isn't going to work here.

Comment: I think I've understood what you're saying. Maybe I can overcome this issue in a different way, I mean, I've used `Maybe Procedure` because I wanted to test if the procedure had something inside the body or not. Going further with the implementation though, inside a procedure body can be declared variables other than simply other procedures so I'm thinking of replacing `{ Nothing }` with `{ [] }` and `{ Just $1 }` with `{ $1 }`, so that inside `DeclarationSequence` I can return a list that could contain procedures or variables. The problem could be: how can I store two types in the same list?

Comment: You can't store two different types in the same list. Whereas this is not exactly true, when you start thinking like that it usually means you are heading down the wrong track. Btw - if you've found any of what I've written helpful, upvoting is appropriate and appreciated.

Comment: I've changed my data structure to not use `Maybe Procedure` anymore and that I won't need a list of two types anymore. I've updated my questione since I stille get some errors due to type mismatch. I've kept track of the production types, but it didn't help too much.

Comment: With your updated parser I'm getting the error `unknown identifier 'KW_VAR'` plus some others when running happy.

Comment: Yes sorry, I've now updated the parser and added the updated lexer too

Comment: I was finally able to solve the problem and I continued with the implementation of this 'compiler'. I'm now struggling to send custom errors while parsing and I've posted a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37059704/3365063)

Thank you very much for all the help you gave me!