# Show custom errors while parsing Happy Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, happy

I'm writing a monadic parser using Alex and Happy in Haskell.

My error function is defined like this:

```
parseError :: Token -> Alex a
parseError _ = alexError "error occurred"
```

How can I send custom errors (like incorrect type while trying to add a string to a number) during parsing?

---

UPDATE

The parser doesn't need to do the type checking, I'm doing it inside the production since I keep track of the operands type.
As said in a comment, I cannot use the `parseError`, so is there a way to print an error and stop the parser?

Comment: Just pass a different string than `"error occurred"` to `alexError`...?

Comment: Ok, but I need to pass the string from my production rule, and `parseError` function only takes a `Token` parameter, not any string I want

Comment: I admit that I'm not very familiar with alex or happy, so forgive me if this is a stupid question, but: if `parseError` doesn't do what you want, why not change `parseError`, or avoid using it entirely in favor of the `alexError` function that does do what you want?

Comment: Well, the definition of `parseError` is like that because it's the definition Happy wants, so I can't change it. Also I cannot use `alexError` directly because it returns a `Alex a` type while I just need to stop the parsing printing the error

Comment: "like incorrect type while trying to add a string to a number" - a parser is not a typechecker, and Happy won't provide any capabilities to easily turn it into one. If you want to typecheck your language, you should parse it into an untyped version, then typecheck that. If you really must go this route, then the code in your production (e.g. for the 'add' rule) must implement the typechecking - `parseError` won't do it.

Comment: Yes of course, the production for my `add` rule checks the type of the two operands so, is there a way to print an error and stop the parser without using `parseError`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it by implementing this function:

```
fatalError :: (Show a1, Show a) => [Char] -> a -> a1 -> t
fatalError s l c = error ("Error at line " ++ (show l) ++ " column " ++ (show c) ++ ": " ++ s)
```

and I call it from the production when an error is detected